# How to kill alert box in Chrome developers tools?

Tags: javascript

example js:

How to kill alert box in chrome developers tools?

in content_scripts -> content.js

```js
window.onload = function () {
   window.alert = function () {}
}
```

but there not effect,help me.

Comment: Of course `window.onload = …` typed into the console won’t achieve anything, if the page _has_ loaded already. Just do `window.alert = function () {}` on its own then.

Comment: @JayBuckman No,I want overide alert in chrome developers tools.

Answer (score 0):

**manifest.json**

```json
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://elearn.ecust.edu.cn:86/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "inject.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
```

**inject.js**

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log("----加载inject.js---DOMContentLoaded")
    window.alert = function () { }
    overrideSelectNativeJS_Functions()
})

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    console.log("----加载inject.js---load")
    window.alert = function () { }
    overrideSelectNativeJS_Functions()
})
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
    console.log("----加载inject.js---beforeunload")
    window.alert = function () { }
    overrideSelectNativeJS_Functions()
})
window.addEventListener("unload", function () {
    console.log("----加载inject.js---unload")
    window.alert = function () { }
    overrideSelectNativeJS_Functions()
})


addJS_Node(null, null, overrideSelectNativeJS_Functions);

function overrideSelectNativeJS_Functions() {
    window.alert = function alert(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}

function addJS_Node(text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
    var D = document;
    var scriptNode = D.createElement('script');
    scriptNode.type = "text/javascript";
    if (text) scriptNode.textContent = text;
    if (s_URL) scriptNode.src = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun) scriptNode.textContent = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild(scriptNode);
}
```